# Perron Frobenius not working on the following matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a nonnegative matrix, but the (left) eigenvector associated with the biggest eigenvalue has also nonpositive entries, and I cannot figure out the reason. Since I'm calculating the left eigenvector the following matrix is transposed. The biggest eigenvalue is 1 since the matrix is stochastic (by row).

$$\pmatrix{0 & 0.5 & 0.5 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0}^T $$

I tried with octave and with python (numpy) and I get the same result.

```
octave:41> m
m =

   0.00000   0.50000   0.50000   0.00000   0.00000
   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   1.00000   0.00000
   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   1.00000
   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   1.00000
   1.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000


octave:43> [vecm,valm]=eig(transpose(m))                                                                                                                                                                                                 
vecm =

  -0.60302 + 0.00000i  -0.59347 + 0.00000i  -0.59347 - 0.00000i   0.49809 + 0.00000i  -0.00000 + 0.00000i
  -0.30151 + 0.00000i   0.06770 + 0.33090i   0.06770 - 0.33090i  -0.38445 + 0.00000i   0.00000 + 0.00000i
  -0.30151 + 0.00000i   0.06770 + 0.33090i   0.06770 - 0.33090i  -0.38445 + 0.00000i   0.70711 + 0.00000i
  -0.30151 + 0.00000i   0.35355 - 0.15099i   0.35355 + 0.15099i   0.59347 + 0.00000i  -0.70711 + 0.00000i
  -0.60302 + 0.00000i   0.10451 - 0.51081i   0.10451 + 0.51081i  -0.32266 + 0.00000i   0.00000 + 0.00000i

valm =

Diagonal Matrix

   1.00000 + 0.00000i                    0                    0                    0                    0
                    0  -0.17610 + 0.86072i                    0                    0                    0
                    0                    0  -0.17610 - 0.86072i                    0                    0
                    0                    0                    0  -0.64780 + 0.00000i                    0
                    0                    0                    0                    0  -0.00000 + 0.00000i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements of your numerical eigenvector all have the same sign, so there is a representative of the eigenspace which has all nonnegative entries (e.g. the one taken by multiplying all the entries of your numerical eigenvector by $-1$). Of course the representative of probabilistic interest is the one with all nonnegative entries and which has a sum of $1$.

Comment: Yeah I'm stupid. I kept reading the matrix as rows not as columns. (tricked by python numpy matrix handling) I'll leave this here. It might be useful for somebody.